# TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined || Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a mute command for my discord bot but when I run:

```js
let mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Muted');
```

I get an error in the console saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
```

as if `message.guild` is undefined, the command works but I get this error in the console. If anyone knows how to get rid of this error any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `message` a valid message object? You can check by trying to log `message.content`

Comment: Pls provide more code, hard to help when you show only 1 code block. 
Based on the error, we can assume 2 options: The message was sent to the DM or the `message` it's not real discord.js message  object.

Comment: @Elitezen yes it is I logged the variable mutedRole and it showed up just fine how it should, think this may be an issue with discord.js

Answer (score 0):

lmao I finally found the issue and it was something completely unrelated to the mute command, when the mute command is executed it dm's the user that they have been muted and that calls the client.on("channelCreate"), which I was not checking for if it was dm's so it was trying to get the guild.roles attribute of a dm.